# php- ctype_alpha isn't working?

Tags: php

I am using the following code to check if:
1. Name is less than than 2 chars
2  Name is greater than 40 chars
3. Name only contains alphabetical letters

```
if (strlen($name<2) || strlen($name>40) || !ctype_alpha($name)) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Your name seems to be invalid'));
    die($output);
}
```

It always returns *Your name seems to be invalid* if I type anything, for eg. Ashish.

What's wrong?

Comment: You are trying to take the string length of a boolean expression …

Comment: No, it doesn’t. Fix the strlen issue – you want to get the length of the name, and compare it to a number afterwards, not the other way around as you are doing right now – you are checking whether the name is greater than 2, and then trying to take the length of that result, which of course makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `strlen($name<2)` should be `strlen($name)<2`

Which changes the code to

```
$name = "HelloWorld";
if (strlen($name)<2 || strlen($name)>40 || !ctype_alpha($name)) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Your name seems to be invalid'));
} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'success', 'text' => 'OK'));
}
var_dump($output);
```

Here is the result of this code: http://3v4l.org/1oAXJ